# Listing Business Accounts under Google My Business API

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-my-business-api

I have authenticated against a Google Account and trying to fetch the Businesses on that account using the Google My Business API.

I can't seem to find any samples on how to do that using the Google NodeJS Client Libraries.

Here is what I tried:

```
async fetchGoogleMyBusinessAccounts() {
    console.log(`Fetching GMB Accounts`);
    let authCredentials= ...
    const oauth2Client = initOAuth2Client(platform, authCredentials);
    google.options({ auth: oauth2Client });
    let gmbAccountManagement = google.mybusinessaccountmanagement(); //There seems to be an issue on this line
    try {
        let myBusinessAccounts = await gmbAccountManagement.accounts.list();
        console.log(`Connected Accounts = ${JSON.stringify(myBusinessAccounts, null, 2)}`);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Error Listing GMB Accounts`);
    }
}
```

But the error I keep getting is:

> Argument error: Accepts only string or object

I can't seem to figure out how what might be wrong and how best to get about this.

Any insights would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing the API version:

```
const mybusinessaccountmanagement = google.mybusinessaccountmanagement('v1');
```